# Outlook 2010 does not open SharePoint 2010 Overdue task

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, outlook, office-integration, workflow-activity

Microsoft Office Outlook 2010 integrates with SharePoint 2010 workflow notifications by providing an option to "Open this Task" on the ribbon. We have an issue where when the user tries to open an overdue task using outlook 2010 the outlook flickers and hence the user has to to kill the outlook.

The user can open the task when an item has been assigned using outlook 2010 but when the same task is overdue the outlook flickers.

I've used fiddler tool to see the error for this issue and i can see error HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error with

Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

ULS logs has same error as Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

I am not sure how to resolve the issue. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did u find that task on the SharePoint site? The error states the task no longer exist, however appearing in the Outlook list could only mean that syncronisation between Outlook and SharePoint has not been succesful. You might also need to re-authenticate with SharePoint from Outlook

Comment: thanks for your resonse. I can see the task is there and the user who is trying to edit the overdue task has contribute permissions.

Comment: Managed to find reason why user was unable to edit the overdue task. It was a permission issue on the task, added user with contribute permission on the task and it worked.One thing that i am not sure about is how the workflow managed to remove the permissions for that user for an overdue task? is this by design?

Comment: Workflow can do anything as they are not always running in the same context as the user operating the site, e.g. could run as Initiator, Creator or even System administrator, therefore could also update permissions.

Comment: Put your solution as an answer, if you've solved the problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but i am not able to resolve it.
I tried checking the user permissions on the list with workflow and tasks list as well. At both places he has contribute permissions.
Please let me know what I am missing as still facing the issue. Thanks
Prakul

Comment: @nishtha : if you have found the resolution to this problem would you please post this as an answer so that other users of the site will be able to find it. Thanks [moderator].

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering an issue where Outlook 2010 does not open SharePoint 2010 overdue tasks, there are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot the problem:

Check Compatibility: Ensure that your version of Outlook 2010 and SharePoint 2010 are compatible with each other. Verify that both applications are updated with the latest service packs and updates.

Verify Task List Permissions: Confirm that you have the necessary permissions to access and view the overdue tasks in the SharePoint task list. Contact your SharePoint site administrator to ensure that the appropriate permissions are granted.

Clear Outlook Cache: Clearing the Outlook cache can sometimes resolve synchronization issues. Close Outlook, navigate to the Outlook cache folder, and delete the contents. The cache folder location can vary depending on the version of Outlook you are using. Once cleared, restart Outlook and check if you can open the overdue tasks.

Repair Outlook Data File: If the issue persists, you can try repairing the Outlook data file (.pst) associated with your account. Open the Control Panel, navigate to Mail, and then click on Data Files. Select your Outlook data file and choose the Repair option. Follow the on-screen prompts to complete the repair process.

Reconfigure SharePoint Task List: Remove the SharePoint task list from Outlook and reconfigure the connection. In Outlook, go to the Tasks section, right-click on the SharePoint task list, and select Remove from Outlook. Then, add the task list again by going to File > Account Settings > Account Settings > SharePoint Lists > Add. Enter the SharePoint site URL and follow the prompts to add the task list.